# Use Guava's ImmutableSortedMap as a frequency map

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I have a problem understanding how to use `ImmutableSortedMap.toImmutableSortedMap()`, when I want to create a frequency map. I know about `Multiset` ([asked about that previously and got excellent help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348128/how-to-use-guavas-multisets-tomultiset-when-collecting-a-stream)), but I don't want to use it this time, because it will require me to write a custom serializer to create a json representation that works for the consumers of said json.

The below code works, i.e. it creates the desired frequency map, sorted on key in ascending order, but it uses a temporary map, which I then use to create the `ImmutableSortedMap`. **I would like to get rid of the temporary map**. My attempts to use `toImmutableSortedMap()` collector method for this scenario failed to produce code that even compiled...

I am using Java 8 and **Guava** version **28.1**

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<String, Long> intermediateMap = Stream.of("b", "a", "c", "b")
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    ImmutableSortedMap<String, Long> desiredMap = ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(intermediateMap);

    System.out.println(desiredMap); // Outputs {a=1, b=2, c=1}, which is the desired state
}
```

Comment: FYI If you're using Jackson, handling new Guava collections is as easy as adding [jackson-datatype-guava dependency](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/tree/master/guava) and using `GuavaModule` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Map<String, Long> result =
        Stream.of("b", "a", "c", "b")
              .collect(ImmutableSortedMap.toImmutableSortedMap(
                  Comparator.naturalOrder(),
                  Function.identity(),
                  x -> 1L,
                  Long::sum
              ));
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to do what the OP asked for with the provided APIs.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me under Java 8?

Comment: It compiles for me if I do Function.<String>identity(), not without <String>. Even though my Intellij says type arguments can be inferred. Same behavior both from Intellij and commad line

Answer (score 2):

You can even achieve something similar (an *unmodifiable*, *sorted* `Map`), without using Guava.

```
Map<String, Long> immutableSortedMap = Stream.of("b", "a", "c", "b")
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()), 
                Collections::unmodifiableMap)
        );
```

- Use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to achieve the sorting (on natural order)
- Use [`Collectors::collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to wrap the result in an unmodifiable map

Comment: I think the point was about the direct usage of `toImmutableSortedMap`, but it's for the OP to decide. And you are still using that intermediate map that the OP complained initially.

Comment: Agree that OP probably wants `toImmutableSortedMap`, but I think the usage of `collectingAndThen` can be an interesting addition for some... The intermediate `Map` is indeed still there, but not it is kinda hidden ;-)